# Subqueries are not allowed after VALUES?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
INSERT INTO t_MT_User (ID, Badge, Name, Scope, comp_code, dept_code, [status]) 
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM t_MT_User), @userBadgeNumber, @userName, @userScope, @companyCode, @departmentCode, 1)
```

This query throws the following error:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

If I change `VALUES` to `SELECT`, I get another error instead:

```
INSERT INTO t_MT_User (ID, Badge, Name, Scope, comp_code, dept_code, [status]) 
    SELECT 
        ((SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM t_MT_User), 
         @userBadgeNumber, @userName, @userScope, @companyCode, 
         @departmentCode, 1)
```

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

How do I achieve `(SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM t_MT_User)` in this context?

Comment: What you doing Actually ??  Inserting a value of ID from Query and other values you adding from Parameters??

Comment: Not able to repro on ssms `create table #t1
(
id int,
id1 int
)

insert into #t1
values
(1,1),
(2,2)

declare @id int=1
insert into #t1
values
(
(Select max(id) from #t1)+1,@id
)`

Comment: If you are after an auto increment on the ID field, set it, this seems like  hack

Comment: As @BugFinder mentioned, if you want to automatically assign a new ID to it, you should implement ID as a auto increment field, and let the database take it's responsibility of creating a new ID for it

Comment: @Icepickle Should I change that at this stage? It's a table with records in production server.

Comment: Well, yeah, it shouldn't have been there in the first place, I guess you could write a db update script, do some proper testing of upgrading the db, and negotiate a planned time to upgrade it in the near future. Better to change it now, than to work around it for the foreseeable time to come

Answer (score 6):

First thing is first - your code, even if you fix it's syntax, is wrong.
Seems like you try to implement your own auto-increment mechanism. **That will fail.**
The correct way is to use SQL Server's built-in mechanism for auto-increment, and create the `ID` columns as an [`Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property).

Then you don't need to include it in the insert statement at all, and you are safe even in a multi-client or multi-threaded environments (which your current implementation will start giving wrong results).

Comment: Can I change that at this stage? It's a table with records in production server.

Comment: Yes. You should, but be careful. Messing with production data must be done by someone that really knows their stuff. Is this `ID` column used for foreign key constraints, or does it have any meaning as a business data?

Answer (score 3):

your syntax is wrong. Should be

```
INSERT INTO t_MT_User (ID, Badge, Name, Scope, comp_code, dept_code, [status]) 
SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 , @userBadgeNumber, @userName, @userScope, 
       @companyCode, @departmentCode, 1
FROM   t_MT_User
```

Comment: While that answer the question, it does not refer to the much more important issue. That's why I didn't include the correct syntax in my answer to begin with, since the entire thing is wrong to begin with.