# incorrect syntax when I select, the error near the first name

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a little problem with an error. but I have this command in another form and do not give me the error.

This is the code:

```
string select = "select CONCAT(nume,' ',prenume) from echipa where email=@EMAIL";

            cmd.Connection = con;


            if (bunifuCheckbox1.Checked == true)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert into clienti_fizici(nume,prenume,email,telefon,adresa,data_nasterii,data_ora,CNP,sex,judetprovenienta,temperamentclient,provenientaclient,descriere,numeagent)values('"
+ bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox4.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox8.Text + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox3.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH: mm:ss") + "','" + bunifuDatepicker1.Value.Date + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox11.Text + "','" + gender + "','" + bunifuMaterialTextbox12.Text + "','" + bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue + "','" + bunifuDropdown2.selectedValue
+ "','" + richTextBox1.Text + "','" + select + "')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", loginform.Email);
                MessageBox.Show("Datele au fost introduse in baza de date !");
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
```

and the error would be from that select.
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Insert the value of the select? Insert the SQL statement as a string? If the first, it won’t work this way. If the second, parametrize the rest of the query also and it will work.

Comment: I have just answered a question like this, check the example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750505/incorrect-syntax-near-s-unclosed-quotation-marks-after-the-character-string/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @mjwills exception states System.Data.SqlClient - meaning SQL Server. Also, using parameters is just a part of the problem. It's not a duplicate of the question you or Rogério linked to. The syntax error is because the use of a `select` inside the `values` clause. If anything, it's a duplicate of [Subqueries are not allowed after VALUES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324426/subqueries-are-not-allowed-after-values). However, I didn't mark it as duplicate since this question has a bigger problem (the SQL injection hazard, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must never concatenate strings with user input to create SQL Statement. Instead, always parameterize your SQL statements. Otherwise you are risking [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Second, you can't use `select` inside the `values` clause.
What you can do add parameters or hard coded values to your `select` statement.

Third, `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` both implement the `IDisposable` interface and should be used as a local variable inside a `using` block.

A better code would look like this:

```
if (bunifuCheckbox1.Checked == true)
{

    string sql = "Insert into clienti_fizici(nume, prenume, email, telefon, adresa, data_nasterii, data_ora, CNP, sex, judetprovenienta, temperamentclient, provenientaclient, descriere, numeagent) " + 
                 "SELECT @nume, @prenume, @email, @telefon, @adresa, @data_nasterii, @data_ora, @CNP, @sex, @judetprovenienta, @temperamentclient, @provenientaclient, @descriere, CONCAT(nume,' ',prenume) " + 
                 "FROM echipa where email = @EMAIL";

    // Note: SqlConnection should be opened for the shortest time possible - the using statement close and dispose it when done.
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // SqlCommand is also an IDisposable and should be disposed when done.
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)
        {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nume", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@prenume", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text;
        //... Add the rest of the parameters here...
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EMAIL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = loginform.Email;
        // Why is this here? MessageBox.Show("Datele au fost introduse in baza de date !");
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i put the parameters and added the selection and now it works.